# SQL to show the course name for each person

Tags: sql, inner-join

I got tables, one contains student details and the second one got course details. I want to write a SQL query that will show the course name for each person picking from two tabels. I'm trying to use the inner join function.

Two tables are,

`SELECT * FROM person_course`

| person | course | course_version_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BA101 | 1 |
| 2 | BA201 | 1 |
| 3 | BA221 | 2 |
| 4 | BA101 | 1 |
| 5 | BA101 | 1 |
| 6 | BA221 | 1 |
| 7 | BA201 | 2 |
| 8 | BA221 | 2 |
| 9 | BA221 | 2 |

`SELECT * FROM course`

| course | course_name | course_version_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BA101 | AA | 1 |
| BA201 | BB | 1 |
| BA201 | CC | 2 |
| BA221 | DD | 1 |
| BA221 | EE | 2 |

Is the query below correct?

```
SELECT person_course.person, course.course_name
FROM  person_course
INNER JOIN course on person_course.course=course.course
AND course on person_course. course_version_number = course .course_version_number ;
```

Can I use the "INNER JOIN" condition with "AND?

The SQL query logic should derive a combination of course & course_version_number to find the name of the course against the person.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: No, it is not correct, because you will get a syntax error when doing this (on most DBMS's)   (for an example of the error on MySQL see: https://dbfiddle.uk/qLkKmtTp )

Comment: *Is the below query correct?* - well what happened when you tried it? (you *have* tried it?)

Comment: Before ask, you can just test query on one of online services like https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/339c544bf197890e3d1b7b277cbd39b8/

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Debug questions require a [mre]. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [ask] [Help] PS "with AND", "derive", "combination", "find" & "against" don't mean anything in particular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT PC.person, C.course_name
FROM  person_course PC
INNER JOIN course C on PC.course=C.course
  AND PC.course_version_number = C.course_version_number ;
```

Comment: Please fix the typo, and explain why this should work.

Comment: What about persons which do not have a course?